# Nuxt3 Layout Css is not updating when route Changes with NuxtLink

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt3

What the below code is supposed to be doing is pretty simple, when the user navigates to the `/blog` route, the layout is set to `blog` and the blog layout has a different header style. The homepage has a different header style as well, but with `NuxtLink` the page layout styles are not updating unless I refresh the page each time.

There are two different layouts:
`default.vue`

```js
<template>
  <AppHeader />
  <slot />
</template>

<style>
.header-wrapper {
  background: red;
}
</style>
```

and the other layout
`blog.vue`

```js
<template>
  <AppHeader />
  <slot />
</template>

<style>
.header-wrapper {
  background: blue;
}
</style>
```

In the pages directory, there are two pages
`index.vue`

```js
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: 'default'
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>this is the homepage</h1>
    <NuxtLink to="/blog">Blog</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>
```

and `blog.vue`

```js
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: 'blog'
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>this is the blog page</h1>
    <NuxtLink to="/">Homepage</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the styles [scoped](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css) in order to be unique for each layout:

```html
<template>
  <AppHeader />
  <slot />
</template>

<style scoped>
.header-wrapper {
  background: red;
}
</style>
```

and

```html
<template>
  <AppHeader />
  <slot />
</template>

<style scoped>
.header-wrapper {
  background: blue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did indeed work